# how can we print table headers on every page in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Table header (thead) wont appear on every page when we give  print command on Chrome browser.I just want every page to have table header after we print the documents.I know how it can be done for IE nad Firefox but i want this feature to be used in chrome also.Chrome browser does not support this feature .Is there any alternative way to impliment this feature.

here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media print
{
  table { page-break-after:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group;}
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th>TH 1</th><th>TH 2</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                             <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                             <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                             <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i have just given a sample program which contains table header and table body..can somebody please help me out.Do i need to do any changes in CSS part of my code??

Answer (score -1):

Your code perfectly work in all browsers.May be you are using very old chrome browser, update it and try again.
checkout the working fiddle :
   jsfiddle.net/pratyush141/nw1fnf37

Comment: hey.no its not working in chrome..i checked it..which version of chrome you are talking about which is working.??